# Web2py Query Legacy Database

Tags: python, data-access-layer, web2py, legacy

I have a legacy database called my_legacy_db which is separate from the normal db.

### my_legacy_db

users
 - email
 - username
 - name

So cliff, your first part would work to generate field names and put everything in a dict to build the query's. The problem is when I do this query:

```
db().select(my_legacy_db.users)

I get this error:
In [20] : db().select(my_legacy_db.users)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/web-apps/web2py/gluon/contrib/shell.py", line 233, in run
    exec compiled in statement_module.__dict__
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/web-apps/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 7578, in select
    return adapter.select(self.query,fields,attributes)
  File "/opt/web-apps/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 1307, in select
    sql = self._select(query, fields, attributes)
  File "/opt/web-apps/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 1196, in _select
    raise SyntaxError, 'Set: no tables selected'
SyntaxError: Set: no tables selected

In [21] : print (flickr_db.users)
users

In [22] : print flickr_db
<DAL {'_migrate_enabled': True, '_lastsql': "SET sql_mode='NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';", '_db_codec': 'UTF-8', '_timings': [('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;', 0.0002460479736328125), ("SET sql_mode='NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';", 0.00025606155395507812)], '_fake_migrate': False, '_dbname': 'mysql', '_request_tenant': 'request_tenant', '_adapter': <gluon.dal.MySQLAdapter object at 0x91375ac>, '_tables': ['users'], '_pending_references': {}, '_fake_migrate_all': False, 'check_reserved': None, '_uri': 'mysql://CENSORED', 'users': <Table 'username': <gluon.dal.Field object at 0x9137b6c>, '_db': <DAL {...}>, 'cycled': <gluon.dal.Field object at 0x94d0b8c>, 'id': <gluon.dal.Field object at 0x95054ac>, 'ALL': <gluon.dal.SQLALL object at 0x969a7ac>, '_sequence_name': 'users_sequence', 'name': <gluon.dal.Field object at 0x9137ecc>, '_referenced_by': [], '_singular': 'Users', '_common_filter': None, '_id': <gluon.dal.Field object at 0x95054ac>}>, '_referee_name': '%(table)s', '_migrate': True, '_pool_size': 0, '_common_fields': [], '_uri_hash': 'dfb3272fc537e3339819a1549180722e'}>
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Is the legacy db not built in /databases right? Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE: I tried as anthony suggested in the model shell:

```
In [3] : db(my_legacy_db.users).select()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/web-apps/web2py/gluon/contrib/shell.py", line 233, in run
    exec compiled in statement_module.__dict__
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/web-apps/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 7577, in select
    fields = adapter.expand_all(fields, adapter.tables(self.query))
  File "/opt/web-apps/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 1172, in expand_all
    for field in self.db[table]:
  File "/opt/web-apps/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 6337, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, str(key))
KeyError: 'users'
```

Now I know that users is defined in my_legacy_db, and all syntax is correct. Is this an error that is there because the db files aren't generating correctly? Or am I still doing something wrong with the select syntax?

Comment: Please show the code you used to define the my_legacy_db connection as well as the "users" table? Also, how did you get into the "model shell"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "users" is the name of a table and you want to select all records and all fields, you would do:

```
db(my_legacy_db.users).select()
```

The query goes inside `db()`, not inside `select()` (`select()` is where you list the fields you want returned, or leave it empty if you want all fields). Note, in the above line, `my_legacy_db.users` is not actually a query but just a table -- that's a shortcut to tell web2py you want all records in the table.

You could also do:

```
db().select(my_legacy_db.users.ALL)
```

That indicates you want all fields, and by excluding the query, it assumes you want all records in the table.

See the [book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/6#Query,-Set,-Rows) for more details.